# How to integrate a Facebook page into my app? Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to integrate a public page into my android app. I've tried to look for some guidance but so far I don't even know where to begin.

What I am looking for basically is for a user to be able to read only that specific FB page's feed, load photos and videos if the post has them, get notified when there's a new post on the page and upon clicking that notification the user should be taken to that post and all of this without each user having to login to facebook. I want to avoid WebView but if I can restrict the user to that specific page instead of the user browsing his facebook through my page then WebView is fine too.

Is what I just described even possible? If so, I realize that this is too big a question but I am just looking for any guidance you can provide or any tutorial you can point me to, it would be a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the app access token. With that it should be possible to fetch a page's feed.